# NestJS/Prisma gives "Error Debug Failure" without any additional info

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

Running my very first, very small, NestJs/PrismaORM application and starting it up I get the following:

```
/Users/bert/Project/helloworld-api_> nest start --debug

 Error  Debug Failure.

/Users/bert/Project/helloworld-api_>
```

(Error is with red background)

**Where can I find more info on the error message?**

I'm sure it's my mistake but it would be nice if NestJS gave me some more info.

To be complete, my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

And the relevant section from package.json is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.13",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.13",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.13",
    "@prisma/client": "^2.18.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.2.7",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.2",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prisma": "^2.18.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  },
```

Hope you guys can help me because I'm a bit stuck here.

Thanks,

Bert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not aware of the root cause of the error, [but the documented fix](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5938) for the moment is to use `typescript@next` and make use of what will become part of `typescript@4.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rebuild everything in the project which had to do with Prisma.
So:

- Remove node_modules
- Remove Prisma and Prisma-Client from package.json
- npm install
- npm i prisma and prisma-client
- Rebuild the module, controller en and service

Then it worked.

But having said that, the solution offered by Jay McDoniel is obviously the real solution, so give your upvotes to Jay. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble, but what was written above didn't help.
So, in service where I need to use PrismaService I change the code to

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PrismaService) private prisma
  ) { }
```

instead of

```
  constructor(
        private prisma: PrismaService
      ) { }
```